# Let $F$ be a field of characteristic p. Is field extension $F/F^p$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have a field $F$ with characteristic $p$. Let's define $F^p = \{a^p \mid a \in F\}$. And we have the field extension $F/F^p$. I see how this extension is algebraic, but can it be an extension of a finite degree? How do I prove it if it's true? I don't really see how it can be finite if the field $F$ is infinite.

Thank you

Comment: It could be of finite degree; it could be of infinite degree.

Comment: to see how it *can* be finite, take $F= {\mathbb F}_p(t)$.

Comment: @peterag Even simpler, take $F$ to be any algebraically closed field, e.g. $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$.

Comment: @WhatsUp acknowledged...

Comment: @N.S. In the last sentence, the OP says "I don't really see how it can be finite if the field F is infinite."

Comment: And you can take the hint of @peterag to cook up a case where it’s infinite.

Comment: @peterag ok thank you. so if I understand correctly. in that case $F^p = \mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$ due to the freshmans dream and finite field properties. So the degree of the extension is $p$? And the basis is for example $1, t, t^2, \dots, t^{p-1}$. Is this correct or am I missing something here.

Comment: Also, lets say I have a field $K$ of characteristic $p$. For me to say that $(K(x))^p = K(x^p)$ I need to know that $K$ is a perfect field right? this does not work in general

Comment: That's right...